# Regex: Matching individual characters only (no characters containted in strings)

Tags: c#, regex

Aim: To split a string `Regex.Split(...)` based on a pattern of individual characters, leaving the character matched at the beginning of a split list.

Problem: One of the characters *can* appear in other parts of the string I don't wish to split on and I'm getting more list items than intended.

Example of string to split: `T 2 TBS PO And > Qd PRN MIX X A 3 TB \ A 4 TB Xmon UG`

Outcome desired:

```
T 2 TBS PO And 
> Qd PRN MIX 
X A 3 TB 
\ A 4 TB Xmon UG
```

Pattern: `(?=[@\+X\\>])`

This works for everything except the `X`. Instead of the desired outcome, I'm getting it split in undesired places.

Current outcome:

```
T 2 TBS PO And 
> Qd PRN MI
X 
X A 3 TB 
\ A 4 TB X
mon UG
```

Basically, I need it to not split on a string of characters only when it's on it's own.

Thanks in advance for your help

UPDATE: Oops! I seemed to have forgot to mention that that the centre of the pattern, the characters to split by, have been pulled from a table and technically, I don't know there's the `X` there beforehand (they may also change.)

For this reason, Jonny 5/Jerry's suggestion seems the most viable to me. I'll test when I get into work.

Comment: Well because there's an `X` in `MIX`. Might want to add white-spaces to the lookaround. And add an additional lookbehind to keep the split zero-width if you like e.g. something like `(?<=\s)(?=[@+X\\>]\s)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I get into work. Cheers, Jonny 5 - you're alive! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put some `\s` in there to make sure the characters you are matching are alone:

```
(?<=\s)(?=[@\+\\>X]\s)
```

`(?<=\s)` makes sure the character is preceded by a space, and the space that follows makes sure the character is followed by a space.

<sup>Note: where 'space' is mentioned above, it actually means whitespace, tab, newline, carriage return.</sup>

Comment: @Deadlykipper Awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Just split your regex into two and piped them:

```
(?=[@\+\\>])|(?=\bX\b)
```

`(?=[@\+\\>])` checking for your regular characters.

`(?=\bX\b)` is checking for alone `X`

Comment: Could be done with one lookahead `(?=[@+\\>]|\bX\b)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not roll your own instead of using a regular expression:

```
public IEnumerable<string> CustomSplit( string source )
{
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < source.Length ; ++i )
  {
    char curr        = source[i] ;
    char next        = i+1 < source.Length ? source[i+1] : ' ' ;
    bool isDelimiter = curr == '@'
                     | curr == '+'
                     | curr == '\\'
                     | curr == '>'
                     | ( curr == 'X' && char.IsWhiteSpace(next) )
                     ;
    if ( isDelimiter )
    {
      if ( buf.Length > 0 ) yield return buf.ToString() ;
      buf.Length = 0 ;
    }
    buf.Append(curr) ;
  }

  // return the last element, if there is one.
  if ( buf.Length > 0 ) yield return buf.ToString() ;

}
```